# cmake's include_directories for custom made python modules

Tags: python, cmake

I have a python project with a CMakeLists.txt and a custom made python module (a *.py file), that is not in the same directory, as the file, containing main. Right I use the ugly `sys.path.append("../../path/to/module.py")`.

How can I tell python, where to search for modules to import? Maybe `include_directories` from cmake will help?

Comment: CMake doesn't help with searching imported modules. CMake even doesn't preprocess python scripts - the scripts are not compiled at all. Your problem is related **only with python**, and described in that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder.

Comment: Why don't you add an answer? Or, should I delete the question?